# Linux command-line utility to remove colors in a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, colors, ghostscript, grayscale

I'm searching for a linux command-line utility/script capable of removing colors in a PDF. The output of the utility should be the same PDF, but in grayscale.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Already [reposted at SU](http://superuser.com/questions/196866/linux-command-line-utility-to-remove-colors-in-a-pdf-file/197734#197734).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Ghostscript:

```
gswin32c ^
  -o grayscale.pdf ^
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
  -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray ^
  -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray ^
  -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 ^
   c:/path/to/input.pdf
```

(example is for Windows; on Linux use `gs` instead of `gswin32c.exe` and `\` as a line continuation mark instead of `^`).

---

#### Update

If color conversion does not work as desired and if you see a message like *"Unable to convert color space to Gray, reverting strategy to LeaveColorUnchanged"* then...

1. your Ghostscript probably is a newer release from the *9.x version series*, and
2. your source PDF likely uses an embedded *ICC color profile*

In this case add **`-dOverrideICC`** to the command line and see if it changes the result as desired.

---

<sub>Also, the original answer contained a typo:</sub>

- <sub>it used <strike>`-sProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray`</strike> (additional forward slash character)</sub>
- <sub>instead of `-sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray` (no forward slash))</sub>

Comment: you actually saved my life. It works on os X as well, just install ghostscript with brew. Jay!